# Facebook Graph API does not return full post data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to fetch a public page feed. I created a basic application to get `appId` and `secret`. When I make a call to `PUBLIC_PAGE_ID/feed` I can retrieve the correct list of posts in JSON, but they are missing all the field I need, [described in docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post), and only have *message*, *created_time* and *id*:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "...",
      "created_time": "2015-06-11T07:57:05+0000",
      "id": "23X12XXXXXX9836_11XXXXXXXX610XXXX52"
    }, 
    ...
```

Why all other data isn't there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The response to your query: `/id/feed` is the default response. To access more data, you have to pass a `fields` parameter with the keyword of data you would like to retrieve.

For example: `<id>/feed?fields=id,message,picture,shares`

This will return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1234567890",
      "message": "Message",
      "picture": "http://fbcdn.com/xxxxxx.jpg",
      "shares": {
        "count": 0
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any other alternative to this? I tried this and all I get back is "id", not posts nothing.

Comment: It can be the solution if you need more fields but without the fields parameter you still don't get back more than id, created_time and message/story. However one of my apps get back everything, it has a user_likes permission and another one doesn't. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

What I could figure out is you should submit the app for review with at least one permission what your app still needs and then you will get back every data what you ask in the fields parameter.